# create post in app and send to server with retrofit

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit2

I want to Post a request to the server. And make a new post in the app.
I am sending a request, but I do not see an answer. I do this in my postman and it works correctly.

This is my request to the server by postman.
I am filling and sending fields.

[postman image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRmrz.png)

And he gives me this answer.

[post man image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J88IH.png)

Well, now you see my code

my request

```
@POST("ads")
    Call<PostCreate> getUpload(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Body PostCreate post);
```

my model class

```
 public PostCreate(String category, String title, String price, String description, String address, String tell) {
        this.category = category;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.address = address;
        this.tell = tell;
    }
```

and my activity createpost code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_post);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started");

        post_title = findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_description = findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        post_phone = findViewById(R.id.post_phone);
        post_price = findViewById(R.id.post_price);
        post_category = findViewById(R.id.post_category);
        post_address = findViewById(R.id.post_address);


        submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String title = post_title.getText().toString().trim();
                String description = post_description.getText().toString().trim();
                String phone = post_phone.getText().toString().trim();
                String price = post_price.getText().toString().trim();
                String category = post_category.getText().toString().trim();
                String address = post_address.getText().toString().trim();
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick submit: called. ");
                createPost(title, description, phone, price, category, address);
            }
        });

    }

    private void createPost(String title, String description, String phone, String price, String category, String address) {
        PostCreate post = new PostCreate(title, description, price, phone, address, category);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Get_Token", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String token = preferences.getString("Token", null);

        Call<PostCreate> call = RetrofitClient.getmInstance().getApi().getUpload("token " + token, post);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<PostCreate>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostCreate> call, Response<PostCreate> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse Retrofit: Called. ");
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: submit" + response.body().toString());
                Toast.makeText(CreatePost.this, "All set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostCreate> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(CreatePost.this, "ERROR: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

And the error that shows me

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.book.Activities.CreatePost$2.onResponse(CreatePost.java:73)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

why null object ? i fill all fields.
can help me ?
Please do not link me to another page
i can null image .

Comment: The NPE seems to come from the `toString()` of `response.body().toString()`, so you should set a breakpoint there, and examine the response object. In your Postman screenshot you get a 400 error from the server, so it could be that you get the same from in your app.

Comment: @Ridcully In postman I sent a blank request that gives error 400 .... and my model true ?

Comment: Can you post the headers you're using in Postman? Perhaps something's wrong with Authorization (it seems odd to me, that the value for Authorization header is `"token " + token` and not just `token`). If you debug, as I suggested you could see if the response perhaps has an HTTP result code of 403 or something, which would suggest a failed authorization.

Comment: @Ridcully no my token is true . Because I'm logged in with the same method